# Dropdown Menu disappears on hover

Tags: css

I want to have a very basic CSS dropdown menu for my website. 
This is the code:

```
#topNav { font-size: 12px; width: 970px; margin: 0 auto; height: 33px; background: url(images/menubg.png); /*border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;*/ }
#topNav ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; margin: 0 auto; }
#topNav ul li { height: 33px; float: left; padding: 0px; font: bold 12px/37px ; }
#topNav ul li a{ padding: 0 18px; height: 33px; float: left; text-decoration: none; display: block;  color: #7b7a76; font: 14px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#topNav ul li a:hover { padding: 0 18px; height: 33px; /*float: left;*/ text-decoration: underline; display: block;  color: #e52128; font:  14px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: url(images/menuover.png); }
#topNav ul li a:active { padding: 0 18px; height: 33px; /*float: left; text-decoration: none; display: block;  color: #666666;*/ font:  14px/37px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: url(images/menuover.png); }
```

and :

```
.nav, .nav ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.nav { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; }
.nav li { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; /*background: url(images/navbg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0 #292929;*/ }
.nav li a, .nav li a:link, .nav li a:active, .nav li a:visited { font: bold 1.22em/25px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #959595; display: block; padding: 0 9px;  text-decoration: none; }
.nav li a:hover { background: /*#f2f2f2*/ #FAFBFF; color: #000; }
#nav-one li:hover a, #nav-one li.sfHover a { background: #fff; color: #000; }
#nav-one li:hover ul a, #nav-one li.sfHover ul a { background: #565656; color: #959595; }
#nav-one li:hover ul a:hover, #nav-one li.sfHover ul a:hover { background: #ccc; color: #000; }
.nav ul { background: #565656; /*background: url(images/navbg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0 #292929;*/ list-style: none; margin: 0; width: 150px; position: absolute; top: -999em; left: -1px; }
.nav li:hover ul, .nav li.sfHover ul { top: 37px; }
.nav ul li { border: 0; float: none; }
.nav ul a { border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom: 0; padding-right: 20px; width: 150px; white-space: nowrap; }
.nav ul a:hover { background: #ccc; color: #000; }
```

The dropdown menu displays ok, but when I hover over the dropdown item, it dissapears.

The menu is in a  and looks like this:

```
<div id="topNav">
        <ul class="nav">
```

I already tried to put it into a wrapper to no avail.

Comment: Do you mind setting up a JSFiddle with this code?  It will be much easier for us to troubleshoot if you do.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely your submenu is 1 or 2 pixels outside of the main menu. This will cause the submenu to 'close' before the mouse can get to it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I changed the top of the submenu below the main menu and it works like it is supposed to do!
Have a good day and thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this, Jeff has what I believe to be the right answer.
[Simple menu 1](http://www.handy-html.com/create-a-simple-css-dropdown-menu/)
[Simple menu 2](http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/)